# How can I read a cookie via SSJS?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs

Is there a way to read cookie values via SSJS?

setting works via 
Platform.Response.SetCookie(...);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. You can read values via Platform.Request.GetCookieValue(cookieName);

```
var myCookie = Platform.Request.GetCookieValue('myCookie');
```

The function returns a string and exposes the HTTP Cookie collection. Returns null when no HTTP Request object is available, or the given cookie name does not exist in the cookie collection.

If you wanted to read all cookies saved where you don't know the name in advance, you could access them through the HTTP header - Platform.Request.GetRequestHeader() function asking for the "Cookie" header and manipulate the resulting string.

Comment: oh you just have to love how those docs are structured... thanks mate! GetCookieValue() works like a charm :)